# Range restrict possible input without hiding

Tags: html, css, range

How can I implement a range slider with visible min equals 0% and max equals 100% but restrict the possible values from i.e. 10% to 90%? See the attached example.

[Slider example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MgB2.png)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yhmr93n4/ Is something in the right direction.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To do that, you need both HTML and CSS. Since this feature isn't implemented within the "range" input, we need to create our custom variation.

The input element has "max" and "min" attributes, it makes it a lot easier because we can already set the minimum and maximum of our range, which is minimum 10% and maximum 90%.

All we need to do now is to create an illusion of the input being 100%, but in reality it isn't.

This is what I came up with:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.slidecontainer {
  display: flex;
}

.normalslide {
  width: 100%;
  background: #93cfed;
}

.limitedslide {
  width: 100%;
  background: #93cfed;
}
.limitedslide input {
  margin-left: 10%;
  max-width: calc(90% - 10%);
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: white;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background: #93cfed;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h1>Limited Range Slider</h1>

<div class="container">
  <p>Default range slider:</p>
  <div class="slidecontainer">
    <span>0%</span>
    <div class="normalslide">
      <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider">
    </div>
    <span>100%</span>
  </div>
  
  <p>Limited range slider (min 10%, max 90%):</p>
  <div class="slidecontainer">
    <span>0%</span>
    <div class="limitedslide">
      <input type="range" min="10" max="90" value="50" class="slider">
    </div>
    <span>100%</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to change the min and max of the slider, just change the input's min and max, then change the "90%" and "10%" values of the "limitedslide" class:

In HTML:

```
<input type="range" min="10" max="90" value="50" class="slider">
```

In CSS (10% is min and 90% is max):

```
.limitedslide input {
  margin-left: 10%;
  max-width: calc(90% - 10%);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This indeed works like a charm. However, for styling reasons it gets difficult to style everything as one piece. Another approach I tested is: http://jsfiddle.net/uwcyma3r/ However I can't get the restricted area to display a different color. Any ideas?

Comment: It appears to be that JQuery creates a custom div as a replacement for the range input with its custom styles. I don't know much about the code behind the JQuery, so I can't give you a good answer. If you want, you can put this code:

`var customSlider = document.getElementsByClassName("ui-slider-track ui-shadow-inset ui-bar-inherit ui-corner-all")[0];
customSlider.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';`

It works, but it's a bit of cheating.
Anyways, if you find my answer helpful, make sure to accept it as an answer. Good luck!